# Using formula output as variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to take the following HStack:

```
HStack {
  Text("BUN/Creatinine Ratio")
  Spacer()
  Text("\((coredata.one / coredata.two), specifier: "%.0f")")
}
```

And apply the following if...then statement to it:

```
if let numberValue = Double(formulaOutput) { //Output from the above formula.
  if (10...20) ~= numberValue {
    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
  }
  else {
    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
  }
}
```

I just can't figure out how to use the output as a variable. Also, is it possible to define more than one range for the "else" statement? <10 = Value 1, >20 = Value 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `switch` for more cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sample code. I also suggest you read again the Swift and SwiftUI basics:

```
let formulaOutput: Double = (coredata.one / coredata.two)
HStack {
    Text("BUN/Creatinine Ratio")
    Spacer()
    Text("\(formulaOutput, specifier: "%.0f")")
}

if (10...20) ~= formulaOutput {
    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
} else {
    Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.circle.fill")
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. I actually tried a version of this code before posting and it didn't work. Now that I've had some sleep, I realized I'd put the let statement in the wrong place. :| I'm still learning, but I appreciate your help!